# Why in drupal files are in .inc extension rather than php?

Tags: files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [when to use include (inc) files in module development](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54737/when-to-use-include-inc-files-in-module-development)

Why they include files with .inc extension, not just .php?

Comment: also why in modules they are using extensions like .module, why not just .php?

Comment: Modules have that extension because, for the code that looks for existing modules, it is easier to look for files using that extension, than looking for every file with extension .php, and then check their content to see if they are effectively modules. The extension used from a file is just a convention. There isn't a specific reason to use .svg for an SVG image; the important is that who uses that type of file agrees on the extension to use.